# "error: no matching function for call to" when constructing an unintialized struct

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I'm trying to use a [`boost::lockfree::spsc_queue`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/lockfree/spsc_queue.html) with this [websocket server](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/broadcast_server/broadcast_server.cpp) instead of a `std::queue` for `m_actions` to contain this `struct`:

```
enum action_type {
    SUBSCRIBE,
    UNSUBSCRIBE,
    MESSAGE
};

struct action {
    action(action_type t, connection_hdl h) : type(t), hdl(h) {}
    action(action_type t, server::message_ptr m) : type(t), msg(m) {}

    action_type type;
    websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl;
    server::message_ptr msg;
};
```

I cannot initialize this `struct` inline with

```
action a = m_actions.front();
```

because `spsc_queue` does not have that function but uses `void pop` to both set the object and `return boolean` for looping.

When I try to

```
action a;
while(m_actions.pop(a)){
    ...
```

`gcc` says:

```
position_server.cpp:106:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘action::action()’
position_server.cpp:106:11: note: candidates are:
position_server.cpp:39:5: note: action::action(action_type, websocketpp::endpoint<websocketpp::connection<websocketpp::config::asio>, websocketpp::config::asio>::message_ptr)
position_server.cpp:39:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
position_server.cpp:38:5: note: action::action(action_type, websocketpp::connection_hdl)
position_server.cpp:38:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
position_server.cpp:37:8: note: action::action(const action&)
position_server.cpp:37:8: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

How can an `action` be constructed and then set with `spsc_queue.pop()`?

Comment: "`action();`" is just a constructor declaration.  You need to actually define it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you don't have default constructor in your `action` class. **It is the constructor that can be called without argument**.

But when you do:

```
action a;
```

You need this constructor:

```
struct action {
    action();  // Default constructor
    // ...
};
```

You should declare and define it.

Default constructors are automatically invoked when an object value is declared with no argument list. (e.g. `action a;`).